# OpenGL: passing dynamically allocated matrices to a uniform

Tags: c++, opengl

The title says it all.

For some reason this code is working:

```
float m[3][3] = {
    {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
    {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f},
    {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}
};
glUniformMatrix3fv(basicShader->uniformAt(5), 1, GL_TRUE, &m[0][0]);
```

But this one isn't:

```
float **m = new float*[3];
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    m[i] = new float[3];
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) m[i][j] = 0;
}
m[0][0] = 1.0f;
m[1][1] = 1.0f;
m[2][2] = 1.0f;
glUniformMatrix3fv(basicShader->uniformAt(5), 1, GL_TRUE, &m[0][0]);
```

Comment: `float[3][3]` is a 2 dimensional array, in a coherent memory block. `float **` is an array of pointers and each pointer points to a new 1 dimensional array.

Comment: Ohhh, that makes sense. So do I have to manually convert `float **` to `float[3][3]` in order to send it to opengl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float* m = new float[9] {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
                         0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                         0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };



glUniformMatrix3fv(basicShader->uniformAt(5), 1, GL_TRUE, m);
```

2D arrays are actually laid out continuously.

EDIT: Just saying, in your first example you don't need `&m[0][0]`. Just `&m` is sufficient because the address points automatically to the first element.

Comment: I was hoping I could keep `float **m` somehow but I guess I can't. But your solution will work. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work just the way the OpenGL function parses the data. It parses 9 consecutive floats from the dereferenced pointer and doesn't dereference the single rows.